# Will specific fillers or chemicals make simple plastic milk cartons more durable, enough to be used as weightlifting plates

Tags: recycling

no code involved and no technical equipment is going to involved in experiment and implementation for business/tech startup that is, in brief, a way for me to exercise during my business studies!  Building branded CROSSFIT exercise equipment with readily available materials.  With reasons, I chose each material following, bicycle tires (cheap rubber known for durability), milk cartons (hoping to combine with chemicals to create ultimate durable and form factor retention), filler

Creating a recipe will take some effort I realize, also i did previous research and there are two routes to go, 3dimensional structures make plastic being recycled more durable mechanically, but the better opportunity is to melt rubber into ingots, treat the milk cartons with low-budget chemicals, and then combine the three aforementioned parts into weight lifting plates.

Help if you can, Im looking for the low budget route that will maximize output with low effort.

What chemicals make plastic more durable with form factor rentention the most possible, and what lubricants and filler will make the combination as durable as possible.

Comment: If this were to be possible, the chemicals required would depend on the type of plastic being used.

Comment: Your post is a difficult read due to some wonky punctuation. I've read it twice and can't figure out whether you're trying to make exercise weights out of recycled plastic or use the milk cartons as a readymade container or mould into which a "filler" will be added to create the weight.

Comment: Agree with @transistor. Unclear what you are asking. Could you draw a picture or diagram maybe?

Comment: [![diagram of rubber tire ingot casting procedure][1]][![diagram of plastic ingot procedure, missing low-budget additive for treatment for milk jug plastic(easy dmg)][2]][2]

[![combination in test tube over burner, into olympic plate][3]][3]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTfzX.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wu2XW.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACBK0.jpg

Comment: The problem is that rubber and HDPE (milk carton material) are both fairly low density.  Weights, by definition, need to be heavy.  Cast iron is cheap, dense and plenty strong enough for weights, which is why you see a lot of cheap cast iron barbells and weights.  If you can't just buy weights from GoodWill or yard sales (or your country's equivalent), consider cruising steel scrap yards for bits and pieces that you can use to fabricate weights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand what you want to do correctly, your plan is to melt down bicycle tires, melt down milk cartons, and then combine those two with some third thing, and create a new product.  Your question is what should that third thing be.  If that is incorrect please edit the question.

Your biggest problem here is that you can't melt down bicycle tires.  The process of creating them is irreversible.  Just google "can I melt down bicycle tires" and you'll get a bunch of pages explaining why you can't do it.  To quote one of the top hits: "it's like un-baking bread".

now milk cartons, you could melt down.  Those are usually just HDPE.  You can modify HDPE by adding other components to tweak certain properties.  However, I doubt you'll be able to do it cheaply, and you certainly won't be able to do it without a lot of "technical equipment" and specialized knowledge.

Sorry to rain on your parade but I don't think what you have in mind is feasible.